# Replace NULL or 0.00 to 00.00 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement that if a column is NULL or '', then replace it with '00.00'. The column's datatype as `VARCHAR(11)` and I tried the 3 approaches shown here. The first 2 did not work for me, then I tried the `CASE`, but it is returning a result of '0.00'. Strictly I need the data as '00.00'

```
COALESCE(SALES_TAX_BASE, '00.00') AS SALES_TAX_BASE
```

AND

```
ISNULL(SALES_TAX_BASE, '00.00') AS SALES_TAX_BASE
```

AND

```
CASE 
   WHEN CAST(SALES_TAX_BASE AS VARCHAR(11)) = '' THEN '00.00'
   WHEN CAST(SALES_TAX_BASE AS VARCHAR(11)) = NULL THEN '00.00'
   WHEN CAST(SALES_TAX_BASE AS VARCHAR(11)) = '0.00' THEN '00.00'
   WHEN CAST(SALES_TAX_BASE AS VARCHAR(11)) = '0' THEN '00.00'  
   ELSE SALES_TAX_BASE 
END AS SALES_TAX_BASE
```

Comment: Why didn't `ISNULL` work? And why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar`?

Comment: `WHEN CAST(SALES_TAX_BASE AS VARCHAR(11)) = NULL` should be `WHEN CAST(SALES_TAX_BASE AS VARCHAR(11)) IS NULL` in the `CASE` statement.

Comment: If the data is coming from another system, could `NULL`s actually be `'NULL'`s (as in the characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT SALES_TAX_BASE, 
 result=ISNULL(FORMAT(NULLIF(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(14,2), Sales_TAX_Base),0),'N2'),'00.00')
FROM SampleTable
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e876bc8a645a753f17ffcb7beae096ed)**

Output:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| SALES_TAX_BASE  | result |
+-----------------+--------+
| NULL            |  00.00 |
|                 |  00.00 |
| NULL            |  00.00 |
| 200.60          | 200.60 |
| 0               |  00.00 |
| 0.00            |  00.00 |
|                 |  00.00 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

Presenatation/formatting should be performed on application layer.

Comment: it must be '00.00' not '0.00' if will convert DECIMAL then it will be '0.00'

Comment: Worry about the format in the presentation layer, and store your numerical data in a numerical data type @Rocky .

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following `case expression` with the multiple `OR` operators as shown below:

```
create table SampleTable (Id int, SALES_TAX_BASE Varchar(20))
insert into SampleTable Values
(1, 'NULL'),
(2, ' '),
(3, 'NULL'),
(4, '200.60'),
(5, '0'),
(6, '0.00'),
(7, NULL)

;with cte as (Select Id,
   CASE 
         WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(SALES_TAX_BASE)), '00.00') = '00.00' 
         OR
           LTRIM(RTRIM(SALES_TAX_BASE)) = ''
         OR
            LTRIM(RTRIM(SALES_TAX_BASE)) = '0'
         OR
            LTRIM(RTRIM(SALES_TAX_BASE)) = 'NULL'
         THEN '00.00'
   ELSE 
         SALES_TAX_BASE 
   END AS SALES_TAX_BASE
From SampleTable
)
Select Id
, try_cast (SALES_TAX_BASE as numeric(18, 2)) as SALES_TAX_BASE
from cte
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f504b5849cc33881491a6a31be820751) demo.

Comment: if you will take int or numeric then '00.00' will get convert into '0.00' this is the actual issue so I change the datatype int to varchar

Comment: @Rocky Just remove the try_cast () part and all other will work for you as expected see at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8fe395b340940131c02120ee27b2f59